# Simple QuickBlox createSession giving 422 (application_id required)

Tags: javascript, quickblox

I have just started with the QuickBlox javascript SDK, but I am getting an error `ServiceProxy.ajax error 422 Unprocessable Entity {"errors":{"base":["application_id or app_id (deprecated) required"]}}` trying to create a session.

my `test.html`:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>QuickBlox API client - Content</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="quickblox-javascript-sdk/quickblox.js"></script>
    <script src="config.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>Test</h2>
  </body>
</html>
```

my `main.js`:

```
QB.init(CONFIG.appID, CONFIG.authKey, CONFIG.authSecret, CONFIG.debug);

QB.createSession(TEST_USER, function(err, result) {
  // callback function
  console.log('callback')
  if (err) {
    console.log(err.detail);
  } else {
  }
});
```

my `config.js`:

```
var CONFIG = {
  appId: 19335,
  authKey: 'UtcSpG3mWkLzVmU',
  authSecret: 'zXx2uFdRXvr5eR-',
  debug: true
};

var TEST_USER = {
  login: 'test1',
  password: 'hello123'
}
```

`error`:

```
POST https://api.quickblox.com/session.json 422 (Unprocessable Entity)
jquery.min.js:4
k.cors.a.crossDomain.sendjquery.min.js:4 
n.extend.ajaxquickblox.js:2549
ServiceProxy.ajaxquickblox.js:49
AuthProxy.createSessionquickblox.js:2391
QuickBlox.createSessionVM590:2
(anonymous function)VM584:762 InjectedScript._evaluateOnVM584:695 InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrapVM584:609 InjectedScript.evaluate
quickblox.js:2491

ServiceProxy.ajax error 422 Unprocessable Entity {"errors":{"base":["application_id or app_id (deprecated) required"]}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is very silly, stumbled across it myself.

You copied the code from Quickblox's site.
The key for Application ID is named 'appId' in the config JSON, while referenced as 'appID' from QB.init

Comment: For future reference, this sort of response would be better as a comment to the original question.

Comment: @Rajesh I think this is fine. It is the correct answer. Why should this be a comment?

Comment: @Rajesh, maybe. But, you see, I didn't have the required reputation to comment.

Comment: @ketanbhatt I got your point Kindly comment on any post once you have sufficient reputation.

Comment: @vedant1811 This does provide an answer to the question. The answerer   may give this type of response as comment if he have a sufficient reputation.

Answer (score 0):

When I tried with your credentials, I got the same error... But when I tried with my own, it worked fine. Can you verify your app credentials and try again?

```js
var TEST_USER = {
  login: 'test1',
  password: 'hello123'
};

QB.init(17704, 'Tbr7Gum6rsHsQNL', 'JbN7JH5QK87sODR', true);

QB.createSession(TEST_USER, function(err, result) {
  if (err) {
    alert(err.message);
  } else {
    alert(result.token);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://quickblox.com/js/quickblox.min.js"></script>
```